# Ошибка типа данных в значения колонки

Tags: c#, winforms

Ошибка:

> "Operand data type text is invalid for max operator"

хотелось бы понять, почему выскакивает данная ошибка, т.к. данные в той колонке имеют тип данных `int`. Если кто-то прояснит, то буду очень благодарен.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Таблица в БД действительно называется [Table]?

Comment: Да, на это завязана другая часть кода и все прекрасно взаимодействует, программа берет данные и выводит их. Ошибка только в этой части

Comment: Выглядит так, как вы показываете одну таблицу, а запрос выполняете в другую.

Comment: Там всего одна таблица со стандартным названием "Table"

Comment: Сам форумы облазил и везде эта комбинация работает, не могу понять почему у меня выводить ошибку.

Comment: Быть может база другая.

Comment: База одна, я сейчас перепроверил подключение, все ок. Если закомментить эти строки, то все другие взаимодействия работают с этой же БД работают, ибо ко всему коду подключена только одна бд.

Comment: Быть может MAX не воспринимает квадратные скобки? Попробуйте создать  алиас AS латиницей и используйте его как аргумент. Вообще называть колонки таким образом - странное решение.